# I have a fairly large table and need to get rows `where column_a <> column_b`, what kind of index do I need?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a fairly large table (~ 100M rows) and this table has two `boolean` columns. Let's call them `a` and `b`. I want to get all rows where `a is not equal to b`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  a <> b
```

Do I need two indices, one on `a` and one on `b` for this, or will a composite index on `(a, b)` also work here?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6 and will be upgrading to 10.1 soon.

Comment: I work in SQL server but I would think as you want to compare the two columns you would use a composite index on a and b

Comment: I found this post on stack overflow and it is for PostgreSQL, it says that doing a composite index on a <> b is a good idea, you can read it here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072513/index-in-two-columns-range-comparisson-within-the-same-table), it also says to put the two values on the same side so you would change your query to be where a - b <> 0

Comment: What is the anticipated spread of equal and not?

Comment: That's a clever solution. This is probably what Gordon meant with the index expression.

Comment: @PM77-1 Normally, `a` and `b` are always equal. However, during a transaction a lot can happen, which might result that a significant number rows will have unequal `a` and `b`. The goal of this query is to fetch all such rows, do some logic and then update `a = b`. You could read `a` as `new` and `b` as `old`. It's difficult to quantify this, as in worst-case, all rows might be touched.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much no index is going to help this query.  If you happen to know that a is often equal to b, then you *could* have an index on an expression.  However, indexes on booleans is not usually recommended.  And, the values would have to be equal most of the time -- think 90% of the time or 99% of the time.

Comment: I was 'afraid` of that. In case of the expression index, do you index on `a = b` or on `a <> b`? I would say the latter, as this gives me the results immediately. Also, I am wondering why indexes on booleans are not usually recommended?

Comment: @forever-living . . . Indexes generally help by reducing the number of reads on the table -- but the reads are to pages, not individual rows.  To reduce the number of reads, you need to significantly restrict the number of rows processed by the query.

Comment: I get that. So I would conclude that I need index on `a <> b`, as usually I expect the number of such rows smaller than the number of rows with `a = b`. From comments above, I should rewrite `a <> b` as `a - b <> 0`in boolean-safe way.

Answer (score 2):

If there are relatively few records with `a<>b`, you could use a conditional index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON thetable (id) WHERE a<>b;
```

The actual index-field `id` is not that imporant, and could possibly shadow an existing unconditional (PK) index. If a and b are nullable (makes little sense for booleans) you could use `a is distinct from b` as a condition.

---

UPDATE:

---

```
-- \i tmp.sql
CREATE TABLE thetable
        ( id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , data text
        , a boolean NOT NULL
        , b boolean NOT NULL
        );
INSERT INTO thetable(a,b, data)
SELECT True, True, 'data_' || gs::integer
FROM generate_series(1,1000000) gs 
        ;

UPDATE thetable SET a = False WHERE id % 37 = 0 ;
UPDATE thetable SET b = False WHERE id % 47 = 0 ;

SELECT version();

DROP INDEX zzzzzz ;
CREATE INDEX zzzzzz ON thetable((a<>b)) WHERE a<>b;
VACUUM ANALYZE thetable;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
-- SELECT COUNT(*)
SELECT id
FROM thetable
WHERE a <> b
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
psql:tmp.sql:2: NOTICE:  drop cascades to table tmp.thetable
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1000000
UPDATE 27027
UPDATE 21276
SET
                                           version                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3, 32-bit
(1 row)

ERROR:  index "zzzzzz" does not exist
CREATE INDEX
VACUUM
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using zzzzzz on thetable  (cost=0.29..9741.19 rows=995000 width=4) (actual time=0.057..193.087 rows=47153 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((a <> b) = true)
 Total runtime: 259.891 ms
(3 rows)
```

---

So, it appears you should have to have exactly the same condition in the index-expression as in the `WHERE` conditional. (and it should possibly match the query-condition, too)

Comment: I don't really understand this. Why is the index-column `id` not important? I am not querying on `id`, so how come the index will be used anyway?

Comment: The syntax doesn't allow an empty list of index columns. So you give it some syntactic sugar. Could be anything: a serial, or a timestamp, or anything.

Comment: I understand that. But my question is more: why will that particular index be used if we query on `a <> b`? The `id` column (or timestamp, serial, ...) is not part of the predicate, so how come we end up using that index anyway?

Comment: It does not apeear to be used here (9.3.5). :-[ It would probably be used for simple conditional indexes, such as `(a=True)`.

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Comment: I will try this out later on 9.6 and 10.1.